# How can I Load image from Centura

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper, guptateamdeveloper, centura

How can I Load an image.Jpg using Centura?
then display it in Centura and be able to load this image as a logo in the qrp reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For  loading the image into a centura image control by setting its property as shown in the below image.

[image: Loading image using image property]

In addition to this you can also load the image pragmatically using any of the below mentioned Sal functions,

1.**SalPicSetImage**

bOk = SalPicSetImage ( hWndPict, strImageBytes, nType )
Inserts the contents of a string to a picture object. The third parameter is a constant.
Parameters
hWndPict Window handle. The handle (or name) of a picture.
strImageBytes String. String buffer which stores the image bytes.
nType Number. The format of the picture contents:.Example for jpg - PIC_ImageTypJPEG

2.**SalPicSetFile**

bOk = SalPicSetFile ( hWndPict, strFileName )
Inserts a file's contents into a picture.
Parameters
hWndPict Window Handle. The handle (or name) of a picture.
strFileName String. The name of the file whose contents are to be inserted into hWndPict.

**Steps for passing an image into Qrp**

1.Declare an Object in the qrp file, as shown in the below image

[image: Declaring an object in qrp file]

2.Assign the above mentioned object to Qrp picture as shown the image below,

[image]

3.Set the above mentioned object in the *output* list.(in centura application)

4.Assign  centura image contents into a *longstring* variable and set it in *Input* list.(In centura application)

5. For copying centura image contents into string variable you can use SalPicGetString().

Comment: Thanks  your reply help me a lot

I got it